# Three.js GLTFExporter transparency issue

Tags: three.js, gltf, exporter

I have a problem with three.js GLTFExporter.

I added a model with a transparent map to the scene.

model in three.js render

[image]

but if i use GLTFExporter to export this model, when i use GLTFLoader to load this model,

It doesn't look like what I showed you before（The transparency of the glass is lost.

The effect after export from GLTFExporter

[image]

What is known so far is that I used transparent maps for this model，when I export the model, the transparency effect disappears.

Could you please provide me with some solutions?

Comment: Adding a transparent texture is not enough by itself - i would suggest studying the API of [THREE.MeshStandardMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=meshstandard#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial) and then trying some of the various transparency options, like `material.transparent = true`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem does have something to do with this attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. The reason for this problem is that after loading the .3ds model at the front end, I exported it as .gltf file. When loading the .gltf file again, part of the attribute values were lost, for example, alphaMap became **null** and .transparent became **false**, so the transparency effect failed.

So far I've solved this problem by modifying the .gltf attribute values:
Set the last item in the array below the GLTF file to 0.1, which represents the transparency of the object

materials.pbrMetallicRoughness.baseColorFactor = [1,1,1, **0.1**]